# DataGrid header cannot be accessed by keyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, accessibility

The header in a `DataGrid` is accessible by mouse. When one clicks on the header the columns are sorted, however the same action cannot be performed by the keyboard as the header does not get the focus. Is there a property I am missing? Or is it possible to sort the column in some other manner?

This is part of my code:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns/>
```

Comment: With straight html, you'd have a `<th scope="col">` for the header and a clickable link or image in the header that has the sorting status (ascending, descending, or none).  You'd also want the `aria-sort` property on the header (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-sort).  However, I'm not sure what .Net does, sorry.

Comment: Since headers don't take focus  any keyboard input would somehow have to "know" which one you meant. That isn't going to happen without fairly significant changes to the templating. There isn't a property you're missing and it's rather more complicated than you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the focus on the header of the column by setting the following property, and once the focus moved to the header, you can sort the column using the 'Enter' key.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
   </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
```